# TypeError: fs.writeFilSync is not a function

Tags: node.js

I am getting this error when trying to write a large string to file. It has worked at least once. But then I am again getting the error below.

It will write an empty file to disc.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
const csv = require("csvtojson");
var jsonexport = require('jsonexport');
const fs = require("fs").promises;

const saveJsonToCSV = jsonObj => {
    jsonexport(jsonObj, function (err, csv) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log("Length", csv.length); //Length 9866161
        var path = appDir + "\\csv\\" +"test.csv"; //Path is valid

        try {
            fs.writeFilSync(path, csv);
            console.log("Done writing:", result);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

TypeError: fs.writeFilSync is not a function
    at C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\tools\checkFile.js:32:16
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\node_modules\jsonexport\lib\parser\csv.js:34:38)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\node_modules\jsonexport\lib\index.js:28:10)
    at saveJsonToCSV (C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\tools\checkFile.js:25:5)
    at remove (C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\tools\checkFile.js:101:21)
    at csv.fromFile.then.jsonObj (C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\tools\checkFile.js:61:29)
    at Object.onfulfilled (C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\node_modules\csvtojson\v2\Converter.js:111:33)
    at Result.endProcess (C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\node_modules\csvtojson\v2\Result.js:76:50)
    at Converter.processEnd (C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\node_modules\csvtojson\v2\Converter.js:178:21)
    at C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\node_modules\csvtojson\v2\Converter.js:171:19
    at tryCatcher 

    (C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
        at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
        at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
        at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
        at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
    C:\Users\jokar38\projects\sgcsv\app.js:50
          throw error;
```

Comment: `writeFilSync` doesn't exists, the right is `writeFileSync` - with File.

Comment: Also, `require("fs").promises` doesn't seem to declare the `sync` version of methods, since this API only transforms callbacks into promises... and synchronous method don't use either of these.

Comment: yes correct promises seems to be missing this. Thanks!